# Self referencing one to many Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-1.5

Say I have a person class like so:

```
class Person(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

However if I wanted to add a parents field that referenced multiple Person objects I run into some issues.

set as a ManyToMany it puts the 'child' as the parent of the intended parent in addition to adding the parent to the child when doing:

```
Person_child.parent.add(Person_parent)
```

but setting it as a ForeignKey will only allow me to set one parent.

How can I create a self referring relationship in Person so that I can add Moms, Dads, Step Parents, Adopted parents, etc without creating specific fields for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secret sauce was adding symetrical=False in a ManyToMany